# How to continue running Rails app from where I left last time?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, capybara

I've been working on a scraper on Ruby on Rails which uses Capybara/Poltergeist to save data into model attributes in a MongoDB database. However the dataset is huge and will take a lot of hours and sometimes I might have distractions like Internet connection and have to start from scratch. Could you please help me to find a method for the app to continue inserting elements to database from where I left last time.

Simplified excerpt of my code is:

```
naming.each_with_index do |namee, j|
    @component=Compo.new
    @component[:component]=gnamees[j]
    @component[:partname]=Array.new

    @session.execute_script("javascript:onSelectPart(#{namee[24..37]});")

    sleep 2

    @session.within_frame('content_consist') do
        sleep 3
        @session.within("form[name=ConsistList]") do
            @session.all('input').each do |z|
                @component[:partname] << z.value
            end
        end

    end

    @component.save

    @session.driver.clear_memory_cache
end
```

And each such @komponent is saved in MongoDB as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ad5b7f678208560bcb21bd"), "component" : "2U-9747 - WARNING GP-WIDE VEHICLE", "partname" : [ "PLATE-MARKER WIDTH ", "BOLT ", "NYLOC NUT ", "WASHER ", "PLATE MARKER FRONT ", "PLATE MARKER FRONT ", "SCREW DRIVE PAN " ]}
```

I want the app look at the latest database entry, and keep on adding new elements after the last one, not starting the scraper from the beggining.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're saving the data in a database, it shouldn't be resource-intensive to re-connect to the database and pick up again. It depends what you're doing. You haven't really explained your code enough to determine.

Comment: I am scraping a JS-heavy website containing information about car parts. My code loops through all cars and extracts their car parts list and saves them as object instances. So, how is picking up done?

Comment: After you perform a single operation (such as writing a record), your database will be in a finite step. How you'd make application state match database state is an individualized problem. What exactly are you having a hard time "picking up" when reconnecting?

Comment: I want to be able to stop, to turn off computer and continue the code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with the following solution: added a boolean attribute `:visited, default=false` to a model through which I have been looping. And at the end of each iteration I have set :visited=true.
And my loop was not `Class.all each do |x|` but rather `Class.where(visited=false).map do |x|`;
Therefore it would continue from where it stopped last time.

Answer (score 0):

How about https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq ?

I think delayed jobs are pretty useful for you